# Responsive and Attractive UI: IDE

Tags: ide

I'm using Kubuntu but I'm looking for an IDE/text editor that is responsive and has a UI unlike others. For example, I use this on Windows 8: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/code-writer/5149f454-94a7-40bc-90ef-eafd38355079

I am looking for a text editor similar to that for Linux that their main purpose is attractive UI and responsiveness.

Comment: You say that it must be unlike others, and also like code-writer. I do not think it is possible to be like and unlike. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/), or Atom (https://atom.io/)? Both editors is available on Linux. Not sure if you can call it a complete IDE, but it is really great text editors for programming and handling data in general.

Comment: Well Atom seems to only be available for Mac and I use Linux, but the first one seems pretty cool and is available for Linux, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user280902 You can run Atom on Linux as well if you compile it from source as mentioned [here](https://atom.io/faq).